# file_put_contents and iconv equivalents in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I want is extremely simple and can be done in `PHP` language literally with one line of code:

```
file_put_contents('target.txt', iconv('windows-1252', 'utf-8', file_get_contents('source.txt')));
```

In Python I spent a whole day trying to figure out how to achieve the same trivial thing, but to no avail. When I try to read or write files I usually get `UnicodeDecode errors`, `str has no method decode` and a dozen of similar errors. It seems like I scanned all threads at SO, but still do not know how can I do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you specifying the "encoding" keyword argument when you call `open`?

```
with open('source.txt', encoding='windows-1252') as f_in:
    with open('target.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f_out:
        f_out.write(f_in.read())
```

Comment: Thanks! I will check it in a second!

Comment: The only problem I see, is that when I write to the file I get an escaped string like `b'!table\r\n!version 300\r\n!....`. In other words, I do not have new blank lines, but instead see `\r\n` printed

Comment: And besides to make it work I have to wrap `f_in.read()` with `str()`. So it looks like `str(f_in.read())`. Otherwise, I get an error message `must be str, not bytes`

Comment: As far as I know that can not happen on Python 3, unless you open the file in a different mode to how I've shown.

Comment: In my case input file (windows-1252 encoded) is uploaded to the server from web client and so, I do not have to make first `open` statement, because I can use `file.read()` right away. Probably this is the whole trouble and I do not know how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Since Python 3.5 you can write:

```py
Path('target.txt').write_text(
    Path('source.txt').read_text(encoding='windows-1252'),
    encoding='utf-8'
)
```